# fadeOut doesn't work when click some div

Tags: jquery, fadeout

I'm trying to do a `fadeOut` in some `img` (`.img-mac-dentro`) when i click in a div called ".close". But the effect only works when i click faster (quickly after the ".cada-cliente" event ends). If i wait a little and execute the ".close", the effect doesn't work and the img (.img-mac-dentro) only disapear without fade or anything else. I don't know what is happening. I think that happens because of delay or something like that. Help please !

```
    $(".cada-cliente").click(function(){
    var altura = $(this).height();
    var largura = $(this).width();
    var top = $(this).offset().top;
    var left = $(this).offset().left;
    $(".overlay").css({"width":largura, "height":altura, "top":top, "left":left}).fadeIn(800,function(){
        $(this).animate({"height":$(window).height(), "top":"0px"},800,function(){
            $(this).animate({"width":"100%", "left":"0px"}, function(){
                    $(".img-mac-dentro").delay(400).fadeIn(400);
            });
        });
    });                 
});
$(".fechar").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().next().find(".img-mac-dentro").stop(true,false).fadeOut(800);
});
```

Comment: WHOA. Thats one huge chunk of code `:O`
could u make it smaller? a fiddle at jsfiddle.net, maybe?

Comment: Code has been reduced hehe. The fadeOut in event click of ".fechar" only works when i do the click quickly after the event ".cada-cliente" ends. If i wait about 5 seconds or more and do the click in ".fechar", ".img-mac-dentro" only disapear.